# Oracle Materialized View from remote table with LONG

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I would like to have a materialised view in an Oracle 11g database that uses a database link to a 9i database.

I have done this for a number of tables, and works well to get round compatibility issues with ADO.NET driver, specifically the latest one for EF6.

The problem is that you cannot have a materialized view containing a LONG column.
You cannot convert LONG to CLOB using to_lob() on a remote table (over db link)

Is there any solution to creating a materialised view from a remote table containing a LONG?

This is what I'd like to be able to do...

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV_WITH_CLOB
REFRESH FAST WITH PRIMARY KEY 
START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE+(5/1440) /* 5 MINUTES */ 
FOR UPDATE AS 
SELECT COL1, TO_LOB(MYLONGCOL) FROM TABLE_WITH_LONG@SOURCE_DB;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope this is a legacy table. `LONG` has been deprecated for a ...long... time and shouldn't be used anymore. You should be creation columns with a `LOB` type (either `CLOB` or `NCLOB`).

Comment: It's an ancient table in old Oracle 9i Database. I still need to interface to it until hardware refresh. Do you have any ideas on how it could be worked? I was thinking of creating views on old db converting to longs to varchar2, only problem is where long values exceed length.  From what i've read, mv from remote view using clob wont work either

Comment: Can you not stage the data on the local DB? `INSERT INTO stg_tbl (LOB_COL) SELECT TO_LOB(LONG_COL) from old_db@remote_tbl;`

Comment: you can't use to_lob (or lob locators) across db link. there are two options I'm looking at, virtual cols with varchar representation of long or losing the longs altogether. thanks for input though

Comment: Ahh thats probably a 9i limitation. What about [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:52297289480186) possibility? Create a view on the `LONG`?